# how to set and get object value in provider ChangeNotifier flutter

Tags: object, flutter, dart, provider

I call an api and put result its in an object when I call a item of this object in provider class it is filled, but when I call this variable out of the provider class sometimes it is filled but sometimes it is null. How?
I call this provider class  like it

```
 await Provider.of<StudentProfile>(context, listen: false).setProfile(
        false, username, context);
```

and my class is

```
 class StudentProfile extends ChangeNotifier {
  StdProfile _info;
 int _val;
 setProfile(statefetch, username, context) async {
 String ip = await getServerIP();

 _info =
    await fetchProfilestudent("$ip/users/getUser/$username", context);
  print(_info.result[0].firstname);
 _val=2;

  notifyListeners();
  }

  set info(val) {
  _info = val;
  notifyListeners();
  }

 StdProfile get info => _info;
}
```

and call provider result with

```
Provider.of<StudentProfile >(context).info.name;
```

Answer (score 4):

StudentProfile's param `_info` is null at the beginning and as you initialize it in the async call `setProfile`, it will be a moment before it initializes that it will be null.

`Provider.of<StudentProfile>(context)` should never be null inside the widget tree below the Provider widget.

But `Provider.of<StudentProfile >(context).info.name` will be null at the beginning and in case the `setProfile` function fails;

To prevent it you can use the `?` nullable operator:
`Provider.of<StudentProfile >(context).info?.name` that will return null but won't throw an error.

Also you can use the `??` operator to give a default value in case `info?.name` is null
`Provider.of<StudentProfile >(context).info?.name ?? 'Default Value'`;

You can learn more about nullable operators in this article https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb

Comment: how to first fill _info param then use it  . i first fill it .it will be fill . i want use of value of _info but shoud not be null how first Confidence that it fill then use it

Comment: If you retrieve the data from a server, you should provide a loading state or a default value. If you can get the data sync you can init the _info var inside StudentProfile() {} init.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is a bit wrong, but we can correct it; If your objective is to work with asynchronous functions, it is very useful if you use future or streams, in the same way indicating which type is going to return said function or in its default without return.

```
Future<void> setProfile(statefetch, username) async {
 String ip = await getServerIP();

 info  = await fetchProfilestudent("$ip/users/getUser/$username", 
 context);
 ...  

 notifyListeners();
}
```

This will help you better manage the data, however this is limited to how fast your service is, for this you can support yourself by using a FutureBuilder to consume it in your widgets or a bool attribute in your provider to control and display a circleProgressIndicator while the query is results.

On the other hand, if you want the value of your `_info` attribute to change after solving the query, equal the value of your query to your `set info` function which would be like this `info = await query ()`, this will cause the `notifyListeners ();` fires notifying changes to all listeners.

or you could also try to load or initialize your attributes in a constructor
but as I mentioned before, it is much limited to the response speed of your service

```
class StudentProfile extends ChangeNotifier {`
  StdProfile _info ;
  StudentProfile(){`
  query().then((value) => this._info = value);
 }
}
```